# Change the window title with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, mpv

I know I can set the window title for every new window via the **MPV.conf** file with:

```
--title="window title"
```

But there are many times I need to change the window title, for the active window, on the go. I want to take advantage of Property Expansion by just temporarily showing the properties when I need them and then turning them of, as my PC is slow.

I  have so far tried with no success:

```
7     --title="window title"
3     title="window title"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I change the window title with a hotkey?

You can use [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) from [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) to do this.

Example:

```
nircmd win settext ...
```

Yyou can set a shortcut using something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) as a wrapper for the above command.

Notes:

- See [NirCmd Command Reference - win](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

---

#### What is nircmd?

> NirCmd is a small command-line utility that allows you to do some useful tasks without displaying any user interface. By running NirCmd with simple command-line option, you can write and delete values and keys in the Registry, write values into INI file, dial to your internet account or connect to a VPN network, restart windows or shut down the computer, create shortcut to a file, change the created/modified date of a file, change your display settings, turn off your monitor, open the door of your CD-ROM drive, and more...

Source [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. This is solution is not ideal, as it is not internal to MPV. I want to make use of [MPV properties](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#properties) but its expensive to have these properties displayed at all times so I am looking for a hotkey solution to turn the title bar on/off on demand.